# ¿Cómo utilizar un COALESCE O ISNULL en palabra reservada IN dentro del WHERE

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, pivot

Tengo el siguiente script, que me genera una tabla pivot:

```
DECLARE @Anio INT = 2016;
DECLARE @Userlogin_Negocio INT = NULL;
DECLARE @NumeroEjecutivoTI INT = NULL;
DECLARE @NumeroFuncionario INT = 6157;

SET LANGUAGE Spanish;

SELECT
    NOMBRE_MES,
    COALESCE([TI], NULL) TI,
    COALESCE([PENDIENTE USUARIO], NULL) Usuario,
    COALESCE([EN ESPERA], NULL) EnEspera,
    COALESCE([CONCLUIDO], NULL) CERRADO,
    COALESCE([RECHAZADO], NULL) RECHAZADO,
    (COALESCE([TI], 0) + COALESCE([PENDIENTE USUARIO], 0) + COALESCE([EN ESPERA], 0)) AS ACTIVO
FROM
    (SELECT
        MONTH(rat1.fecha_ingreso) AS NUMERO_MES,
        LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, rat1.fecha_ingreso), 3) AS NOMBRE_MES,
        et.ET_NOMBRE_ETAPA AS ETAPA,
        COUNT(DISTINCT rat1.IDT1) AS CANTIDAD
    FROM
        ALLRATIONAL rat1
        INNER JOIN RAT_PA_ESTADOS est1 ON est1.EST_NOMBRE_ESTADO = rat1.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
        INNER JOIN RAT_PA_ESTADOS_ETAPAS et ON et.ET_CODIGO_ETAPA = est1.EST_CODIGO_ETAPA
    WHERE
        YEAR(rat1.fecha_ingreso) = @Anio AND
        rat1.usuario_negocio_login = COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), @Userlogin_Negocio), rat1.usuario_negocio_login) AND
        rat1.num_gestor_negocio = COALESCE(@NumeroEjecutivoTI, rat1.num_gestor_negocio) AND

        rat1.NOMBRET4 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS IN
            (SELECT SU_NOMBRE_SISTEMA
            FROM RAT_PA_SISTEMASxUSUARIO
            WHERE SU_NUMERO_FUNCIONARIO = @NumeroFuncionario)
    GROUP BY
        MONTH(rat1.fecha_ingreso), LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, rat1.fecha_ingreso), 3), et.ET_NOMBRE_ETAPA) SOURCE
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(SOURCE.CANTIDAD) FOR SOURCE.ETAPA IN ([TI], [PENDIENTE USUARIO], [EN ESPERA], [CONCLUIDO], [RECHAZADO])
    ) AS PIVOTABLE
ORDER BY
    NUMERO_MES ASC;
```

Así cómo esta me funciona bien, el `WHERE` hace los filtros deseados, pero cuando asigno la variable `@NumeroFuncionario = NULL` no me retorna ningún registro, yo necesito que si `@NumeroFuncionario` es `NULL` entonces no tome en cuenta ese filtro y me retorne datos.

Cómo puedo hacer eso? intenté poniendolo así:

```
rat1.NOMBRET4 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS IN
            (COALESCE( (SELECT SU_NOMBRE_SISTEMA
            FROM RAT_PA_SISTEMASxUSUARIO
            WHERE SU_NUMERO_FUNCIONARIO = @NumeroFuncionario) , rat1.NOMBRET4 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS))
```

Y cuando es `NULL` si funciona, pero cuando ese parámetro `@NumeroFuncionario` tiene un valor me muestra el siguiente error:

> La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto
>   cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza
>   como expresión.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE SU_NUMERO_FUNCIONARIO = (CASE WHEN @NumeroFuncionario IS NULL THEN 
SU_NUMERO_FUNCIONARIO else @NumeroFuncionario END)
```

Si `@NumeroFuncionario` es null o cero y quieres todos los registros.

Comment: por que publicas mas de una respuesta?

Comment: modifica tu respuesta agregando una explicacion del codigo, revisar [answer] , saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Al igualar comparar una variable con `NULL` usando SQL Server de ser con `IS NULL` o `IS NOT NULL` en caso de la negación.

En tu caso en lugar de usar `@NumeroFuncionario = NULL`  intenta con `@NumeroFuncionario IS NULL`.

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta... en síntesis, que debo poner en mi script para que funcione?

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, espero que quede más claro :)

Comment: No amigo ese no es el error, cuando digo NumeroFuncionario = NULL me refiero a esto: DECLARE NumeroFuncionario INT = NULL, a la asignación de variable. De igual forma gracias aunque el problema no es ese.

Comment: Ah ok, estaba confundido al respecto, voy a darle otra revisada a tu código para ver qué está pasando

Answer (score 0):

> Y cuando es NULL si funciona, pero cuando ese parámetro @NumeroFuncionario tiene un valor me muestra error

Debes revisar si la tabla `RAT_PA_SISTEMASxUSUARIO` posee valores **NULL** en la columna `SU_NOMBRE_SISTEMA`.

*Si he comprendido bien tu problema* te sugiero aplicar estos cambios:

1. Cambia tu subconsulta de esta manera:

   ```
   SELECT TOP 1 SU_NOMBRE_SISTEMA
   FROM RAT_PA_SISTEMASxUSUARIO
   WHERE SU_NUMERO_FUNCIONARIO = @NumeroFuncionario
   ```

*Explicación:* Ya que tu subconsulta te devuelve más de un valor, en este caso solo traerías el primer elemento que cumpla la condición del `WHERE`.

2. De acuerdo a la [siguiente respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284329/4092887), puedes editar tu consulta SQL de esta manera:

   ```
   SELECT TOP 1 SU_NOMBRE_SISTEMA
   FROM RAT_PA_SISTEMASxUSUARIO
   WHERE SU_NUMERO_FUNCIONARIO = COALESCE(NULLIF(@NumeroFuncionario, ''), SU_NUMERO_FUNCIONARIO);
   ```

*Sin embargo*, como te comentaba, tu subconsulta trae mas de un registro, por ello, antes de hacer este cambio, comprueba porqué obtienes mas de un dato en la subconsulta.

Comment: Necesito validar que el NumeroFuncionario que ingreso a esa pagina se le muestren sólo los registros donde tiene asignado alguno de esos sistemas, por eso es que necesito poner un IN allí y no utilizar un top(1). Ese es el problema que tengo

Comment: @AlonsoFallas otra opción puede ser: _armar_ tu script de la manera en que se muestra en esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/532510/4092887). Allí creas una condición para que modifiques tu consulta SQL. Suerte.

Comment: Es una buena idea, voy a intentar con esa opción, Gracias @Mauricio